# Pivot out dataframe to single row with columns labeled with prefix

Tags: python, pandas

So currently I am trying to collapse a 7x2 table into a 1x14 table and have the 8 columns in the final dataframe be prefixed with the original column labels. I have a feeling my answer lies within `.pivot()` but not sure how to get there. This is what I have so far:

Original Table:

```
              polarity  subjectivity
  count       1.0         1.0
  mean        0.0         0.0
  min         0.0         0.0
  25%         0.0         0.0
  50%         0.0         0.0
  75%         0.0         0.0
  max         0.0         0.0
```

I want to get to here:

```
  subjectivity_count    subjectivity_mean   subjectivity_min    subjectivity_25%    subjectivity_50%    subjectivity_75%    subjectivity_max    polarity_count  polarity_mean   polarity_min    polarity_25%    polarity_50%    polarity_75%    polarity_max
  0      1.0                  0.0               0.0             0.0             0.0             0.0             0.0             1.0             0.0             0.0             0.0             0.0             0.0             0.0
```

I'm able to do that but in a very hacky way. My steps are:

1) Transpose the original df, select one row as index, and add a column prefix

```
df.T.loc['subjectivity'].add_prefix('subjectivity_') 

df.T.loc['polarity'].add_prefix('polarity_')
```

2) Concatenate these together using `pd.concat`

3) Creating a new `pd.DataFrame` constructor on this and transposing.

This is a very ugly way to get the job done and seems inefficient since I'm creating a new `DataFrame` object every time I do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you're looking to do.

```
a = list(np.linspace(0,50))
b = list(np.linspace(0,100))
df = pd.DataFrame({'polarity':a, 'subjectivity': b})
df1 = df.describe()

df2 = df1.reset_index().melt(id_vars = ['index'], value_vars = ['polarity','subjectivity'])
df2['name'] = df2['variable'] + '_' + df2['index']
df2 = df2[['name','value']].set_index('name').transpose()
```

For information on melt, you can go [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

Comment: To make this more widely applicable (aka copy-and-pasteable), set `value_vars` to `df1.columns`.